# Как вернуть свои коды ошибок Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Пишу сервис на Spring Boot. Необходимо возвращать в виде JSON код ответа и его описание. Код ответа необходим при обработке ошибок в сервисе.

На данный момент отправляю его с помощью Map. Если нужно вернуть данные, пихаю их туда же.

Мне кажется, или возвращать коды ответа таким образом - дурной тон? И если да, то как принято реализовывать данный функционал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создавать свои ошибки, указывая через аннотации код ответа сервера и сообщение об ошибке. В случае выкидывания кодом такой ошибке в процессе обработки запроса спринг автоматически преобразует оную в JSON ответ со всей нужной информацией и код ответа будет соответствующий:

Пример на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)

```
@ResponseStatus(
    value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
    reason = "User with this email already exists"
)
class UserAlreadyExistsException : RuntimeException()
```

---

Если же надо изменить код для ответа без ошибки, то можно так (код на [java](/questions/tagged/java)):

1. Указываем возвращаемый тип метода контроллера как `ResponseEntity<?>`
2. Возвращаем из метода контроллера `new ResponseEntity<>(someObjectThatWillBeSerializedToJsonBySpring, HttpStatus.CREATED);` или `ResponseEntity.status(201).body(someObjectThatWillBeSerializedToJsonBySpring)`

Либо можно попробовать добавить аннотацию для метода контроллера: `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)`

Comment: Хорошо, это в случае пробрасывания исключения. А если мне нужно передать код успешного завершения операции?

Comment: @АртёмБондарев, обновил ответ

Comment: Отлично, это почти решает мою проблему. Что можно сделать, если я хочу использовать собственные коды ошибок? Например: Code.CREATED, Code.REMOVED и т.д..

Comment: @АртёмБондарев, попробуйте вот такое возвращать из метода конроллера: `ResponseEntity.status(201).body(someObjectThatWillBeSerializedToJsonBySpring)`